# Align text input vertically (dynamic height)

Tags: html, css

I have created a dynamic height input as follow which scales when browser resize. The second step that I would like to achieve is to vertically center the input text. I use `vertical-align: middle` but it seems that nothing changes.

What could I do to vertically align the input text

```css
input{
  background: lightgray;
  vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    padding-top: 30%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your input has a `padding-top: 30%;` you can just say `padding: 15% 0;` instead so your text will be dynamically centered within your `<input>`.

```css
input{
  background: lightgray;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15% 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Seems good to me. Upvoted for you but let see if there is more elegant solution

Comment: Good Idea but as soon as any text is entered the actual fiex aspect ratio would be lost. The text will change the height...Perhaps with `box-sizing:border-box`?

Comment: @Paulie_D Adding text to the input won't change the height because the height is already accounted for in the input. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your concern though.

Comment: If you add text to it the height will be 30% *plus* the line-height so it won't maintain the 100:30 aspect ratio.

Comment: In the way that the OP had it, it would be no different. For them, `height: 30%;` wasn't doing anything, and it was all based on the `padding-top: 30%;`, which is why I removed `height: 30%;` from my answer. But I see your concern because its height isn't truly 30% of the body, but I was just answering it based on how the OP had it set up, as a 30% height was not defined as a request in the description, but in the code itself. Nenad's answer is the correct one if the OP wanted a true 30% height.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `padding-top` and by default text in input will be centered.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
input {
  background: lightgray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Text">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But by removing the padding it defeats the purpose of dynamic height input as the height does not change according the width .

Comment: It changes according to parent element height which in this case in `body`.

Comment: hmm a good alternative that can be considered in another use case. but the input should scale accordingly to it owns ratio for my case which is 100:30 and not the parent